# popup onload not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I want a popup that only appear when onload. I'm using the [magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/)
the script is working but it display an error on the popup saying that "The image could not be loaded." not sure what is the best `'type'` I need to use with the one im' using.

HTML:

```
<div id="pop">
<img src="something.jpg">
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {src: '#pop'},type: 'image'}, 0);
});
```

CSS:

```
#pop {display:none;}
```

Comment: are you sure that you are using the plugin correctly? [https://i.imgur.com/7aJWOvj.png](https://i.imgur.com/7aJWOvj.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use the magnificPopup library:

```js
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
      src: '#pop',
      type: 'inline',
    },
    type: 'image'
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
#pop {display:none;}
.mfp-content #pop {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">

<div id="pop">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png">
</div>
```

Several changes:

1. If you use an element which is not an image as an item you should specify the type: inline
2. The `display: hidden` is still applied to the element event inside the magnificPopup, so I added a `display: block` for that element when it's inside the magnificPopup wrapper.

---

Another options is to use the image that is inside the `#pop` element:

```js
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
      src: $('#pop img').attr('src')
    },
    type: 'image'
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
#pop {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">

<div id="pop">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `magnifyPopup.open()` on the `<div>`, not the `<img />`. Try calling it directly on the image.

```
<div id="pop">
    <img src="something.jpg" id="img" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#img'
            },
            type: 'image'
        });
    });
</script>
```